# Jenkins maven build reports Failed despite success in Jnuit

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit

I have junit test method like below, It doesn't have any assert statement it has to success obviously and it is success in Local. But When I run the same in Jenkins it says the test case is failed.

```
@Test
public void defaultTestCase(){
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

Jenkins Output:

```
Results :

Tests in error: 
defaultTestCase(com.odr.test.MultiTenancyTest)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Do I need to have any additional settings in Jenkins?

Comment: Obvious question: Why do you have such useless Tests?

Comment: I have many test cases thats also getting failed despite they are success in Local. So commented out all other test cases and had this test case to debug. This is simple test and its also getting failed

Comment: pls provide error messages

Comment: Jenkins output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is an error in setup method that occurs only in the server where Jenkins was running. The error doesn't logged in Jenkins console, So I got confused.

The error was logged here `<JENKINS_WORKSPACE>target/surefire-reports` and identified the error and fixed it.